# Adding order actions like "Print" or "RePrint"

Tags: c#

The eventual desire to implement code that's clean and extendable. I always fear that I'm overusing `If`'s and or not seeing the appropriate pattern to reduce conditionals.

Now I love `architecture`, `micro service's` etc I even enjoy `IoC`, `ISP(SOLID)` But when it comes down to small `encapsulated` methods, the nuances of reducing `If`'s , I struggle to grasp.

I know I've instantiated concrete types and coupled the responsibility(May have just answered my own question). The reality is, I want to minimize the use of `If`'s.

Could I kindly request a Code Review on the below snippet?

```
public async Task AddOrderActionAsync(Identity identity, 
    string value, 
    string order_number)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        var client = await _context.tbl_Client.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c =>
                            c.ClientKey == identity.ClientKey);
        try
        {
            // See if order action exists, if it does it could contain multiple
            // so delete all and re-add one
            var orderAction = _context.tbl_OrderActions.Where(o => 
            o.tbl_Client.ClientKey == identity.ClientKey &&
            o.OrderNumber == order_number).ToList();

            if (orderAction != null && 
                orderAction.Count() > 0)
            {
                _context.tbl_OrderActions.RemoveRange(orderAction);
               await AddOrderActionAsync(_context, identity,
                                       value, order_number);
            }
            else
            {
                await AddOrderActionAsync(_context, identity, value, order_number);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (AddOrderActionException ex)
        {
            new Email().SendEmail(identity.ClientName,
                    "Add Order Action Error - Data API",
                    "Add Order Action Error(" + value + " - " + order_number + "): " + ex.Message,
                    "error@retain.me");

            //System needs to run regardless if this fails
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is adding an "OrderAction" which could be "Print" or "RePrint", there is a possibility that multiple could be added else where in the pipeline or another app. The ideas is to remove the multiple and re-add one an/or just add.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There aren't too many `if`s in this code. However, what you can reduce is indentation and it will help readability.

This code:

```
public async Task AddOrderActionAsync(...)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        // Everything here
    }
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
public async Task AddOrderActionAsync(...)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return;

    // Everything here
}
```

With the nice side-effect to also remove negation.

---

Looking into the code you check `orderAction != null`, it seems you try to be *defensive* here but it's misleading because it can't be `null`. Ever. Also `orderAction.Count() > 0` is equivalent to `orderCount.Any()` which is shorter, faster and communicates better the intent. Content of the `else` clause is repeated then one of them should be dropped:

```
if (orderAction.Any())
    _context.tbl_OrderActions.RemoveRange(orderAction);

await AddOrderActionAsync(_context, identity, value, order_number);
```

In your query you're using `.ToList()` but it's unnecessary and without it EF (or ORM you're using) *might be* able to optimize database calls (if not then you at least gain in clarity).

---

It's not a rule but an accepted convention in C# to do not use underscore to separate words, a variable named `order_number` should be `orderNumber`.

---

You're catching a specific exception, nice! However I think it can be thrown only by `AddOrderActionAsync()` then it should be the only part inside `try`/`catch`:

```
try
{
    await AddOrderActionAsync(_context, identity, value, order_number);
}
catch (AddOrderActionException ex)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Really don't ignore t3chb0t's suggestion about dependency injection, sending e-mails like that it's definitely not something you want to happen inside your unit testing...

Comment: Just to add: `.ToList()` will force evaluation of the expression and instantiate a list at that point; without it the expression is evaluated later when accessed. Disagree about removing brackets for an if statement, especially in C#.  Bracketing conditionals means avoiding simple errors like https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/ (but your point about the return still stands)

Comment: @BurnsBA yes, it's a reason to use it but in _this_ case is pointless (the next line we call `.Any()` on it and it will possibly force evaluation). If you always do it then you will impact performance. Sometimes greatly.

Comment: About braces, well it's a matter of style. Honestly I don't like `if (condition) { return; }` (split over 4 lines)  then I usually omit braces for simple conditions like this but I don't really have any strong argument against the other way. BTW I didn't mean to "remove braces" from an if statement, just to avoid nesting whenever possible (with or without braces, even more when without...)

Comment: Really appreciate the input/answer - I generally do use DI, avoiding tight coupling. A few solid points not sure why I neglected some techniques that I already know...

Comment: "no braces on simple if's" - I've embraced this fully. It goes very well with otherwise well written and formatted code. But Caveat Emptor! In a code-barf context no braces is dangerous. Made worse by the jerk who, thinking he's the smartest guy on the block, puts no whitespace around brace-less conditionals and exercises the semi-colon less option in languages like vb script. Yes, Chuck, I mean you.

Comment: Do you mean **Chuck Norris**?

Comment: No, because “It works on my machine” always holds true for Chuck Norris.

Comment: Chuck Norris’s first program was `kill -9`

Answer (score 8):

## `if`s

> ```
> if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
>     {
> ```

You should avoid unnecessary nesting and turn this condition into a positive one so that you return whent the value is null-or-empty:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
{
    return;
}
```

---

> ```
> if (orderAction != null && 
>     orderAction.Count() > 0)
> ```

Conditions like this one are hard to follow. You should use a helper variable that describes what you are checking:

```
var orderActionExists = orderAction != null orderAction.Count() > 0;
```

*(if this is what it means)*

```
if (orderActionExists) {..}
```

or if you can use at least C# 6 then just:

```
var orderActionExists = orderAction?.Count() > 0;
```

---

## Dependency Injection

> ```
> new Email().SendEmail(identity.ClientName,
> ```

This line screams for dependency injection. Creating the `Email` like this is not a good design because you code depends on the `Email` and you cannot change its behaviour during testing. You cannot exchange it and provide some fake-email.

---

## Other

> ```
> catch (AddOrderActionException ex)
> {
>     ...
>     //System needs to run regardless if this fails
>     return;
> }
> ```

You do not need this `return`. The method will return without it anyway because there is nothing more to do.

> ```
> //System needs to run regardless if this fails
> ```

What if other exceptions are thrown like when Entity Framework could not save the data? If you want to make this *bullet-proof* then catching the *generic* `Exception` might be better unless you know what you are doing and the app should really fail when something else happened.

Comment: Thank you very much, same as above - solid examples, to clean up the code. +1 for DI, I generally do use. Really appreciate the time invested.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you never use your `client` variable, you should remove it as it's an unnecessary call to the DB.

Also, since you use `FirstOrDefault`, you should check at some point if it's `null`. If it shouldn't be ǹull`ever, use`First`.

Comment: Your quite right! It's not being used!!!. As I'm passing in the Identity from my auth service. Huge thumbs up, and upvote!

Comment: @TezWingfield Your IDE usually has tools to detect unused variables, you should use that! :p

Comment: Haha brilliant, to be fair I just neglected it, as I've been refactoring code ( I would of picked it up eventually :P )